# How do I get the item boxes on Sonic Pinball in Casinopolis?

Tags: sonic-adventure

How do I get the extra-life item boxes on the left and right sides of the Sonic Slots Pinball table in Casinopolis?

[image: Sonic Pinball with item boxes circled]
<sub>[Image from Sigma 7 on StrategyWiki.org](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/File:SA_Casinopolis_Slots.png)</sub>